# navigationController property is declared in UINavigationController.h but is a property of UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am new to Ios development and I am following the Big nerd book to learn it. I have a confusion over the "navigationController".
for instance in my class that is an instance of  `UITableViewController` (same for any subclass of `UIViewController` as well) I have this :

```
[[self navigationController]
     pushViewController:detailViewController
     animated:YES];
```

when I look at apple documentation this `navigationController` seems to be a property of `UIViewController`, but is said that it is declared in `UINavigationController.h` !
I opened the `UIviewcontroler.h` and there is no property or method for `navigationController`, but as the documentation says it is indeed in `UINavigationController.h`

it does not make sense at all . first of all I know that a child class inherits the property and methods of the parent class, but `UITableViewControler` is by no mean a subclass of `UINavigationController` ,but a child of UiViewController . So hopefully some one understand what  I am asking. How I am able to access to this property when I am not inheriting from `UINavigationController` ? and how the documentation can show that as a property of `UiViewController` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UINavigationController.h includes a UIViewController category that declares a `navigationController` property.

Remember, filenames are just conventions — they don't actually mean anything to the language. The code inside the files is what matters. Just because some code is inside UINavigationController.h doesn't mean it's inside the UINavigationController class. A header file "belonging" to one class is perfectly free to declare categories on other classes to help them interact with the class that the header is focused on.

Comment: Thank you. You seem very knowledgeable . I'm coming from Java background that's why this is not the usual thing for me .

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a UINavigationController, it will automatically set itself in the `navigationController` property of every UIVIewController. Since UITableViewController inherits from UIVIewcController, it will also have that property.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationController): Look for `navigationController`. You should see this:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController
```

It's under "Getting Other Related View Controllers"

Comment: if in any project in xcode , you go under UIKit.framework --> Headers --> UIViewContoller.h   ,   there is no navigationController property , the above property is defined inside UINavigationController . so my question is still the same and unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation controller object manages the currently displayed screens using the navigation stack. At the bottom of this stack is the root view controller and at the top of the stack is the view controller currently being displayed. Because the UINavigationController class inherits from the UIViewController class, navigation controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a navigation interface, you must install this view as the root of whatever view hierarchy you are creating. UITableViewController inherits from UIViewController can therefore access the UINavigationController property. Refer
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I am still confused, as you are saying both UITableViewController and UINavigationController inherit from UIViewController, so this property is defined inside UINavigationController , not UIViewController , and I do not understand how an instance of UIViewController  can access to this property.